# Composable keeps looping infinitely when changing MutableState<Flow<List<Object>>> value

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I am composing a lazy row of items from firebase. I want to have a row of buttons to filter by the type of place (e.g., shop, restaurant, etc) which works fine. Since they are both the exact same screen, I am just calling the composable for it with the category selected, I then want to be able to select one of the new buttons to filter even further but for some reason the composable gets caught in a loop.

```
fun LocationScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    useCategoryTag: CategoryTags? = null,
    onLocationClick: (String) -> Unit,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
        val locations = viewModel.getCategoryLocations(useCategoryTag).value.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())
        ...
```

In my view model

```
var locations: MutableState<Flow<List<Location>>> =
        mutableStateOf(emptyFlow())

...
...
...

fun getCategoryLocations(tag: CategoryTags?): MutableState<Flow<List<Location>>> {
        if (tag == null) {
            Log.i("getCategoryLocations","null")
            locations.value = firestoreRepository.locations
        } else {
            Log.i("getCategoryLocations","not null")
            locations.value = firestoreRepository.getLocationCategory(tag, locationTags.toList())
        }
        return locations
    }
```

My data access (filtering is just a test value atm)

```
override fun getLocationCategory(
        tag: CategoryTags,
        filters: List<LocationTags>
    ): Flow<List<Location>> {
        return firestore.collection(LOCATIONS_COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo("category", tag.toString())
            .snapshots()
            .map { snapshot ->
                snapshot.toObjects<Location>()
                    .filter { location -> location.top_tags[0] == "Few People" }
            }
    }
```

When a button is clicked the on click triggered is like this with the if null check seeming to work perfectly fine (it simply navigates)

```
onClick = {
    if (useCategoryTag == null) {
        viewModel.onCategoryClick(item as CategoryTags, onLocationClick)
    } else {
       viewModel.getCategoryLocations(useCategoryTag)
    }
}
```

Log just does this:

```
2023-03-21 20:47:24.876 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:24.893 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:24.917 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:24.948 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:24.978 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:24.997 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:25.028 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:25.044 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
2023-03-21 20:47:25.060 13143-13143 getCategoryLocations    com.app.senseaid                     I  not null
```

Have tried using if statement to check if it should be recomposed but made no progress

Edit: It is also looping initial composition now

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The Firestore API doesn't seem to work the way you'd like. You can't create a dynamic query flow like this. Instead, you will have to create your own flow and update it when manually consuming queries.

Try this:

In the repository:

```
private val _locations = MutableStateFlow<List<Location>>(emptyList<String>())
val locations: StateFlow<List<Location>> = _locations
private val tagFlow: MutableStateFlow<CategoryTags?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
fun updateTag(tag: CategoryTags?) = tagFlow.update { tag }
init {
    coroutineScope.launch { // I assume you have a way to inject a couroutineScope for the repository
        tagFlow.collect { tag ->
            val collection = firestore.collection(LOCATIONS_COLLECTION)
            val query =
                if (tag == null) collection
                else collection.whereEqualTo("category", tag)
            query.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                val newLocations = snapshot.toObjects<Location>()
                    .filter { location -> location.top_tags[0] == "Few People" }
                _locations.update { newLocations }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel:

```
val locations = firestoreRepository.locations
fun onCategoryClick(tag: CategoryTags?) = firestoreRepository.updateTag(tag)
```

In Composable screen:

```
val locations by viewModel.locations.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
...
onClick = { viewModel. onCategoryClick(item as CategoryTags) }
```

Comment: I have an issue with locations.update requiring <List<Location>> where my two firestore functions return <Flow<List<Location>>> I used .last() to solve this but not sure if that is right. 
The other problem I have when I try what you've suggested is the getCategoryLocations function is never triggered and my LazyColumn is empty. I can add more screenshots of code if that helps.